# Se genera una linea blanca entre div padre y div hijo

Tags: css

Estoy aprendiendo a usar css y me surgió el siguiente problema, creé un div padre con dos divs dentro y me genera una linea blanca entre el div padre y el hijo de la parte superior. No sé la razón de esta linea ya que probé quitando el padding, los margenes y demás y sigue apareciendo. El div padre es el que lleva el nombre de "Caja" (Se que no deberia llevar otro nombre) y el div hijo en el que se generan las lineas es "Caja-encabezado" las lineas se generan vertical y horizontalmente arriba y a la derecha del div hijo donde va el titulo "Cuadrado"

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
/*Encabezado*/

.Encabezado{
    background-color: rgb(33, 157, 224);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0;

}
.Encabezado-titulo{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.Encabezado-descripcion{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
/*Respuestas*/
.respuesta{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;

}
.respuesta p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
/*Contenedor*/
.Contenedor{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    
}
/*CAJAS*/
.caja{
    width: 40%;
    height: 650px;
    border: 3px solid coral;
    border-radius: 17px;
    margin: 15px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    
}
/* Encabezado de la caja*/
.caja-encabezado{
    background-color: coral ;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    
    
}
.caja-principal{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;

}
.caja-principal__texto{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    
}
.caja-principal__input{
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    color:coral ;
    border: solid coral;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.caja-encabezado__btn{
    background-color: rgb(255, 127, 80);
    color: white;
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.caja-encabezado__btn:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 46, 46);
    cursor: pointer;

}
.caja-encabezado__btn:active{
    background-color: rgb(254, 189, 103);
}

/*Para responsive*/
@media screen  and (max-width:){
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Figuras geometricas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Encabezado-->
    <header class="Encabezado">
      <h1 class="Encabezado-titulo">Figuras geometricas</h1>
      <p class="Encabezado-descripcion">
        Calcular las diferentes medidas de figuras geometricas, como el area y
        el perimetro
      </p>
    </header>
    <!-- Respuesta-->
    <div class="respuesta">
        <p>El area de cuadrado es: 4cm</p>
    </div>

    <section class="Contenedor">
        <div class="caja">
            <div class="caja-encabezado">
                <h2>cuadrado</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="caja-principal">
                <p class="caja-principal__texto">¿Cuanto mide cada lado del cuadrado</p>
                <input class="caja-principal__input" type="number" name="lado" id="lado">
                <button class="caja-encabezado__btn" type="boton">perimetro</button>
                <button class="caja-encabezado__btn" type="boton">Area</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="caja">
            <div class="caja-encabezado">
                <h2>cuadrado</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="caja-principal">
                <p class="caja-principal__texto">¿Cuanto mide cada lado del cuadrado</p>
                <input class="caja-principal__input" type="number" name="lado" id="lado">
                <button class="caja-encabezado__btn" type="boton">perimetro</button>
                <button class="caja-encabezado__btn" type="boton">Area</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="caja">
            <div class="caja-encabezado">
                <h2>cuadrado</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="caja-principal">
                <p class="caja-principal__texto">¿Cuanto mide cada lado del cuadrado</p>
                <input class="caja-principal__input" type="number" name="lado" id="lado">
                <button class="caja-encabezado__btn" type="boton">perimetro</button>
                <button class="caja-encabezado__btn" type="boton">Area</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tienes en el HTML bro ?, dejanos ver

Comment: No especificas cuales son los padres y los hijos, no muestras el HTML, no muestras cuales son las líneas blancas.. si son verticales.. horizontales o ambas.. una pregunta poco especifica

Comment: @MateoGuio  Ya lo modifiqué, agregué el html y el css completo, las lineas que aparecen son las que están arriba y a la derecha del titulo "Cuadrado" este esta en el div hijo "Caja-encabezado" que está en el div "Caja" Disculpen las molestias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una propiedad en CSS llamado `outline`. Que tal si prueba ésta propiedad en vez de `border`.

> ... es usada para establecer el estilo del contorno de un elemento. Un
> contorno es una línea que se dibuja al rededor de elementos, fuera de
> los límites del borde, para resaltar un elemento ([documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/outline-style)).

> Nota: ¡ El contorno difiere de los bordes ! A diferencia del borde, el
> contorno se dibuja fuera del borde del elemento y puede superponerse a
> otro contenido. Además, el contorno NO forma parte de las dimensiones
> del elemento; el ancho y la altura totales del elemento no se ven
> afectados por el ancho del contorno ([w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp)).

```css
*{ 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body{ 
 font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; 
 font-size: 20px;
} 

.Contenedor{ 
 width: 90%; 
 padding: 10px; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 1000px; 
} 

.caja { 
 width: 40%; 
 height: 650px;
 outline: 3px solid coral; 
 border-radius: 17px; 
 margin: 15px; 
 padding: 0;
 float: left; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative; 
}

.caja-encabezado{ 
 background-color: coral; 
 text-align: center; 
 padding: 15px 0; 
 color: #fff; 
 margin: 0; 
 width: 100%; 
}

.caja-principal{ 
 text-align: center; 
 padding: 10px; 
} 

.caja-principal__texto{
 font-size: 20px; 
 font-weight: bolder; 
} 

.caja-principal__input{ 
 height: 40px;
 width: 200px; 
 font-size: 18px; 
 font-weight: bolder; 
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 color:coral; 
 border: solid coral; 
 border-radius: 5px; 
} 

.caja-encabezado__btn{ 
 background-color: rgb(255, 127, 80); 
 color: white; 
 width: 120px; 
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 10px; 
 text-align: center;
 margin: 5px; 
 border-style: none; 
 border-radius: 5px;
} 

.caja-encabezado__btn:hover{
 background-color: rgb(255, 46, 46); 
 cursor: pointer; 
} 

.caja-encabezado__btn:active{ 
 background-color: rgb(254, 189, 103); 
}
```

```html
<section class="Contenedor">
   
   <div class="caja"> 

<div class="caja-encabezado"> 
 <h2>cuadrado</h2> 
</div>

<div class="caja-principal">
 <p class="caja-principal__texto">¿Cuanto mide cada lado del cuadrado</p> 
 <input class="caja-principal__input" type="number" name="lado" id="lado"> 
 <button class="caja-encabezado__btn" type="boton">perimetro</button> 
 <button class="caja-encabezado__btn" type="boton">Area</button> 
</div> 
   
   </div> 
 
  </section>
```